Access to network folder from command line (Google Drive)
I have managed to link a Google account to Google Drive using Dolphin.
Everything works as expected. Files and folders are being created and synced.
My problem comes when I try to access it via the command line.
As far as I see, when I edit the configuration, the folder is located at:
remote:/gdrive-network

Dolphin shows it as:
gdrive

Looking for a solution I have seen that some users have pointed to the folder:
/run/user/1000/.gvfs

I don't have that folder or anything related to gvfs. I have searched the entire drive for that keyword.
I also have seen other users recommending installing rclone, but I would like to make it work as it is, without installing anything else.
How would you access this network drive from the command line?

Are you sure it is possible? As far as I know GDrive is not a normal file system so you can't use regular filesystem tools. I suspect you will need some compatibility layer and you can't just mount it.

you are right that is not a normal file system, but you can mount it with rclone. I posted an answer with the details, thanks for your help.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to access if the remote folder is not mounted. That is the whole problem. The plugin that sets it up with Dolphin is Kio-gdrive and that is not meant to be used with the command line. Some users reported bugs on their forums thinking exactly what I was trying to do. You can't access through the command line with that plug-in because it doesn't mount the drive into a location that a console can read.
The way to go is rclone. I know I said in my original question that I didn't want to use rclone but it is the only way I could get it to work.
In case you are struggling to get it to work, these two guides worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04:
https://rclone.org/drive/
https://ucr-research-computing.github.io/Knowledge_Base/how_to_mount_google_drive.html
